# Can I remove name prefix without contaminate name data?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have tried to remove prefix from the name. Now I use re.sup method to remove the prefix but some of the name are contain a character that included in the prefix.

## Data example

```
-MisterClarkKent
-Mrs.Carol
-missjanedoemiss
```

I tried re.sub(r'(^\w{2,5}\ ?)', r'', name) to remove prefix with fix the position but it won't work because I have more than 10 prefix and each prefix has different size.

```
import re
name = 'mrjasontoddmr'
filter_name = re.sub(r'mr', r'', name)
print(filter_name)

#The result of filer_name is jasontodd but what I want is jasontoddmr
```

I expect the output of "jasontoddmr"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the count and ignore the case with the provided arguments in re.sub().

```
import re
names = ['MisterClarkKent','Mrs.Carol','missjanedoemiss', 'mrjasontoddmr']
filter_names = [re.sub(r'mrs?\.?|mister\s?|miss\s?', r'',name, count=1, flags=re.IGNORECASE) for name in names]

filter_names

Out[99]: ['ClarkKent', 'Carol', 'janedoemiss', 'jasontoddmr']
```

The `?` means the character is optional so in `mrs?\.?` bother `s` and `.` are optional so it can capture both `mr or mr.` and `mrs or mrs.`.